# save files to storage folder in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, webserver, storage

I tried to store files to storage folder in laravel after I uploaded the laravel project on webserver(byethost7.com server ), but the files couldn't be stored to the  storage folder;only stored to  public folder,

i excuted this command on cmd:

```
>php artisan storage:link
```

my config the filesystems.php:

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path(),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],



'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

ImageController:

```
$product=new Product();

$image = $req->file('image');

$image_url = $image->store('images');

$product->image_url = $image_url;
```

showimages.blade.php:

```
<img class="img-thumbnail " src="{{asset('storage/images/'.$product->image_url)}}"/>
```

in web.php:

```
Route::get('getimages',function(){
    return view('showimages');
});
```

But always I get 404 not found error!

Comment: you just need to change config in your filesystems.php file 
```'storage' => [ 'driver' => 'local', root' => storage_path('app/storage')],```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your image like this:

$imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file->extension();

$request->file->storeAs('public/images/', $imageName);

I hope it helps :)

p.s this link should help you:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/crud-with-image-upload-in-laravel-8-exampleexample.html